# Applying a gradient to a sloped div

Tags: css, css-shapes

I've used the following CSS to make a trapezoidally shaped div, using the CSS trick with angled borders:

```css
#slopedDiv {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 100px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #DC0714 transparent;
  border-width: 248px 125px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="slopedDiv"></div>
```

Is it possible to apply a vertical linear gradient to the resulting shape? I've tried using `border-image` but this just causes it to lose the angle as far as I have been able to manage it.

Comment: I am favoring this one, hope that someone will find a solution!

Comment: not worth an answer, but for the fun : gradient + mix-blend-mode where it works ... http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/aJGmxo

Answer (score 3):

One option could be use `skew()` on a pseudo-element instead of the border trick like this:

```css
#slopedDiv {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slopedDiv:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height:100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(11, 11, 87, 1) 0%, rgba(150, 66, 87, 1) 100%);
  transform:skew(-25deg) translateX(-50px)
}
```

```html
<div id="slopedDiv"></div>
```

---

#### Sloped div with Text

```css
#slopedDiv {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slopedDiv div {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(11, 11, 87, 1) 0%, rgba(150, 66, 87, 1) 100%);
  transform: skew(-25deg) translateX(-50px);
}

#slopedDiv h2 {
  color: white;
  letter-spacing:2px;
  padding: 25px 30px;
  transform: skew(25deg) translateX(50px);
}
```

```html
<div id="slopedDiv">
  <div>
    <h2>My Title Here</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I love this - great job!

Comment: Thx @NickyTheWrench :)

Answer (score 3):

If the background behind the div is of known color, you can achieve this result using 2 gradients on the background of the element. One is the gradient that will be seen, the other is a diagonal gradient that hides it (in this case, white)

```css
.test {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-71deg, white 100px, transparent 100px), linear-gradient(to bottom, green, yellow, blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do a border image gradient, seen here:

https://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/

From my testing this won't work with a height of 0, though. You're pretty limited to using pseudo-classes to achieve this, I don't think you'll be able to use a gradient + trapezoid strictly with borders on a 0-height div.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15629012)

Comment: @thebluefox I tried a few different ways of adding the essential parts in-line here, but none of them worked with his application, so instead I just left alternative information along with the reason why his way wouldn't work. The link didn't answer the question. It provided a different option.